# How to Render Irregular Sprite Sheets in SDL2

Tags: c++, user-interface, sdl-2, sprite-sheet

I have a sprite sheet that's 155 x 66 pixels that I use for my game's UI, I see many topics regarding rendering sprite sheets by using the number of pixels and dividing by the number of sprites. The problem with this for me is being a GUI, the buttons on the sprite sheet cannot perfectly align so I'm left with different sized sprites on the sprite sheet. As shown below. How do I render the sprite sheet in SDL2? [Irregular Sprite Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpF63.jpg)

Comment: You'll need extra data, like names and sizes of elements. Write it to e.g. text file and load alongside your image.